# On Error During Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have this code setup which inserts data into a table from another, and it is setup on a loop. I would like for it to check to see if the record it was supposed to upload actually uploaded and if it didn't I would like for it to try again, then after the second try if it still cant I would like for it to terminated the code. Basically:

Before this code runs a connection check is run prior then if there is a connection the record uploads, then during the loop process I would like for it to run a select statement to find the record that was just uploaded on the new table. If it finds it, then it continues onto the next record, if it doesn't it tries one more time, then stops if it still cant. This is one way for me to verify the connection.

It is a way to kind of test the connection during the actual upload process so I don't have to build in a connection check after each record, thus saving time. I am just unsure how to build in an On Error in a loop, are there any ideas? The bottom of the code looks like:

```
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
On Error GoTo Update_qdfError
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
On Error GoTo 0

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Exit Function

Update_qdfError:
For Each err In DAO.Errors
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & err.Number
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since VBA doesn't have structured error handling, you would do the error testing one line at a time in your loop by setting the [On Error propert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)y and then checking the [ERR object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  First, set it up so it falls over to the next line of code like this.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Then, test.

```
Do While rs.EOF
    rs.Fields("fieldName").value =value
    if Err.Number >0 then
        'you had an error

    end if
Loop
```

Comment: Where would I add this in?